# Load UIViewController from a button inside a tableviewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton

I have a button inside a tableviewcell which is inside a tableview (obviously) and the tableview is inside a viewController which is inside a navigation controller

UINavigationCont --> ViewController1 --> UITableView --> UITableViewCell --> UIButton --> (launch a new controller from the IBAction of this button)

How can I accomplish this? 
Thanks

```
- (IBAction)addButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    ViewController1 *detailViewController = [[ViewController1 alloc]init];

    [self.superview.delegate presentPopupViewController:detailViewController animationType:MJPopupViewAnimationFade];
}
```

Comment: Are you using a nib or storyboard?

Comment: Why are you using your own button to do this rather than just going to detail controller on cell selection or using the accessory button that you can add to a cell? This is the "normal" way to do this, using didSelectRowAtIndexPath or tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have your navigation logic inside the controller, not the cell (which I suppose it's the case since you have called `self.superview`. Move your `addDetailViewController` method to your view controller and all your troubles should go away.

Comment: That's simple, but each cell has a button, so that button has to initiate this. Or is there another way?

Comment: Yes you could either have all your buttons call this one single method and access the cell through them using superview (getting the index path). Alternatively , you could have a method in your cell class as you have now, but don't call any navigation code there, just forward the call to your view controller, (this way you will know the index path as well) and manage the navigation in the view controller.

Comment: how do you forward the call?

Comment: you simply call the method (which implies you have a weak reference to your view controller from your cell). You can have it as a delegate, so you'll call `[self.delegate pressedDetailButtonInCell:self]` where the delegate (your view controller) would have to implement a protocol that has `pressedDetailButtonInCell:` in it.

Comment: Ok, I did it another way (but your way seems more direct) I created an index attribute for the cell, in cellForIndex I set the index = index.row. Then I set the tag of that button to this value. In my IBAction, I read the tag, and load the corresponding object from the array matching that index

Comment: That's all right too, however, it forces the button to know to much. He's simply a button, he should not know what an index path is. If for example you would have sections too(not just rows, using the tag will become harder. You would probably have to subclass your button. Anyway, as long as you keep you navigation logic in the controller, your way is correct as well.